# What is the significance of the title of A Clockwork Orange?

Tags: a-clockwork-orange

I believe *A Clockwork Orange* was the title of the book written by the author who lives at "Home", who is first victimized by Alex, then rescues him, then victimizes him. But what does the title mean?  What is its significance with regards to the movie?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockwork_orange#Title) has the author himself giving three possible explanations.

> - That he had overheard the phrase "as queer as a clockwork orange" in a London pub in 1945 and assumed it was a Cockney expression.¹ In
>     Clockwork Marmalade, an essay published in the Listener in 1972, he
>     said that he had heard the phrase several times since that occasion.
>     However, no other record of the expression being used before 1962 has
>     ever appeared.[3] Kingsley Amis notes in his Memoirs (1991) that no
>     trace of it appears in Eric Partridge's Dictionary of Historical
>     Slang.
> - His second explanation was that it was a pun on the Malay word orang, meaning "man." The novel contains no other Malay words or
>     links.
> - In a prefatory note to A Clockwork Orange: A Play with Music, he wrote that the title was a metaphor for "...an organic entity, full of
>     juice and sweetness and agreeable odour, being turned into an
>     automaton.

(Personally, until fairly recently I had always read it as meaning an Orange Clockwork (with the adjective following the noun), but then I realized that the word "Clockwork" is an adjective modifying the noun "Orange".)